# Tabulator: cell.getValue() is not a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, tabulator

I'm using tabulator with the following setup:

```
<link href="utils/tabulator/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="utils/tabulator/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<!-- Output the data as a JSON object in a hidden field -->
<input type="hidden" id="jsonData" value='<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>'>
```

And my JS is:

```js
var tabledata = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("jsonData").value);
var tabulatorColumns = tabledata.length > 0 ? Object.keys(tabledata[0]).map(function (key, index) {
            if (key === "file_id" && index === 0) {
                // Hide the file_id column
                return {
                    title: key,
                    field: key,
                    width: 0,
                    visible: false,
                };
            } else {
                // Create an anchor tag in the first column linking to the corresponding file_id entry
                return {
                    title: key.replace(/_/g, " ").replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1 $2"),
                    field: key,
                    width: 150,
                    headerFilter: "input",
                    headerFilterPlaceholder: "Filter",
                    headerFilterFunc: "like",
                    headerFilterLiveFilter: false,
                    headerFilterEmptyCheck: function (cell) {
                        return cell.getValue() === null || cell.getValue() === "";
                    },
                    headerFilterParams: {
                        allowEmpty: true,
                    },
                    headerSort: true,
                    headerSortTristate: true,
                    headerSortStartingDir: "asc",
                    formatter: function (cell) {
                        if (index === 0) {
                            var file_id = cell.getRow().getData().file_id;
                            var cellValue = cell.getValue();
                            if (file_id) {
                                return "<a href='" + file_id + "'>" + cellValue + "</a>";
                            }
                        }
                        return cell.getValue();
                    },
                };
            }
        }) : [];

        var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
            data: tabledata,
            layout: "fitColumns",
            columns: tabulatorColumns,
        });
```

The table displays completely fine and even the formatter works exactly how I want it to, but I get the following error on trying to filter:

Uncaught TypeError: cell.getValue is not a function
at Object.headerFilterEmptyCheck [as emptyFunc]

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO, did you understand what `TypeError: cell.getValue is not a function` means ?

Comment: Hi @vaku yep. I figured it means that the cell does not have a function called getValue. I'm assuming this is because "cell" is not a _cell_, I just cannot figure out why

Comment: Try Printing `cell` value just before calling `cell.getValue`.

Comment: `headerFilterEmptyCheck` function does not have a `cell` argument, the argument passed to this function is the value of the filter.

Comment: To echo what @timur said - the cell param is wrong but also `headerFilterEmptyCheck` is probably only doing (trying to do) what the default implementation does anyway and so is redundant (based only on my reading of the docs!).

Comment: @Timur @shunty yep. Changing it to `true` worked for me. No clue why I chose to do it how I did it above.